# Create session for java login REST service.

Tags: java, session, authentication, jax-rs

I am trying to set up a session management over a simple login service I have written using JAX-RS. The code might not look good:

```
@Path("/login")
public class Login {

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}/{pass}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public HashMap<String, Boolean> isUserValid(@PathParam("id") String id, @PathParam("pass") String pass) {

    // retrieve user map from database
    DatabaseController db = new DatabaseController();
    HashMap<String, Boolean> validation = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
    validation.put("isValid", false);

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> user : db.user().entrySet()) {
        if ( id.equals(user.getKey()) && pass.equals(user.getValue())) {
            validation.put("isValid", true);
        }
    }
    return validation;
}
```

Does someone know how I can set up a session management on this service.

Answer (score 0):

Rest web services are meant to be stateless , if you want statefull service use soap , there is a dirty hack around it but is not secure use a authentication token along with every request of rest and keep client states like browser , ip etc. in a database along with the token so that u know for a change in client or any attack.

Answer (score 0):

By default every webservice should be stateless. It's not the best idea to use webservices in a session-based way. Sometimes there is a need for this but keep in mind that the key idea of webservices is the orchestration of services which contradicts with sessions. (See "[Perspectives on Web Services](http://www.springer.com/br/book/9783540009146)" by Zimmermann).

If there is no other way to accomplish your target, see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e13734/stateful.htm#WSADV234).